# pam service restart

Tags: restart, pam

I added the option, umask=007, for pam_umask.so module. Then I logged out and logged in. It works perfectly.

However since I'm studying Ubuntu Linux I want to know how to restart only the specific service. That is the beauty of the linux, isn't it?

What is the command for restarting the pam service?

Comment: Are you referring to `sd-pam`?

Comment: "However since I'm studying Ubuntu Linux I want to know how to restart only the specific service. That is the beauty of the linux, isn't it?" Which service? What beauty? Why do you think there's a PAM service?

Comment: I edited /etc/pam.d/common-session file. How do I make it effective without logging out and logging in?? BTW, the answer for 'what beauty' is in my question.